# SegFault file.c not found (Works on other computers)

Tags: cython

I have a really odd problem with Cython.

I've tested my package on Mac OS and Arch Linux without failure.

Now when I test my package on CentOS I get a Segmentation Fault

Here's the gdb trace

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__Pyx_GetItemInt_Fast (o=0x2aaac56d3b90, i=2, boundscheck=0, wraparound=0, is_list=0) at myprog/Snv.c:10678
10678   myprog/Snv.c: No such file or directory.

(gdb) where


#0  __Pyx_GetItemInt_Fast (o=0x2aaac56d3b90, i=2, boundscheck=0, wraparound=0, is_list=0) at myprog/Snv.c:10678
#1  0x00002aaabe7a8b76 in __pyx_f_3sv2_3Snv_tokenize_vcf (__pyx_v_Bam=<optimized out>, __pyx_v_Variant=<optimized out>, __pyx_optional_args=<optimized out>) at myprog/Snv.c:6685
#2  0x00002aaabe7ac6a2 in __pyx_pf_3sv2_3Snv_6c_preprocess_snv (__pyx_self=<optimized out>, __pyx_v_masked=<optimized out>, __pyx_v_Bam=<optimized out>) at myprog/Snv.c:5374
#3  __pyx_pw_3sv2_3Snv_7c_preprocess_snv (__pyx_self=0x2aaac56d3b90, __pyx_args=0x2aaaab221870, __pyx_kwds=0x2aaab712d690 <__pyx_pw_5pysam_9libctabix_13TabixIterator_5__next__>) at myprog/Snv.c:4916
#4  0x00002aaabe7b7ca1 in __Pyx_PyObject_Call (kw=<optimized out>, arg=<optimized out>, func=<optimized out>) at myprog/Snv.c:10555
#5  __pyx_pf_3sv2_3Snv_2preprocess_snv (__pyx_self=<optimized out>, __pyx_v_masked=<optimized out>, __pyx_v_Bam=<optimized out>) at myprog/Snv.c:2994
#6  __pyx_pw_3sv2_3Snv_3preprocess_snv (__pyx_self=0x2aaac56d3b90, __pyx_args=0x2aaabe4f2f38, __pyx_kwds=0x2aaaaab41240 <PyCFunction_Call>) at myprog/Snv.c:2935
#7  0x00002aaabe579680 in __Pyx_PyObject_Call (kw=0x0, arg=<optimized out>, func=0x2aaabe4f2d40) at myprog/Preprocess.c:9226
#8  __pyx_f_3sv2_10Preprocess_sv2_preprocess (__pyx_v_Bam=0x2aaac56d3dd0, __pyx_v_ofh=0x2aaac56d22d0, __pyx_v_seed=0x619558, __pyx_v_gen=0x2aaaab23b150, __pyx_v_tmp_dir=0x2aaac5ce6bb8) at myprog/Preprocess.c:3527
#9  0x00002aaabe591307 in __pyx_pf_3sv2_10Preprocess_preprocess (__pyx_self=<optimized out>, __pyx_v_tmp_dir=<optimized out>, __pyx_v_gen=<optimized out>, __pyx_v_seed=<optimized out>, 
__pyx_v_ofh=<optimized out>, __pyx_v_Bam=<optimized out>) at myprog/Preprocess.c:2837
#10 __pyx_pw_3sv2_10Preprocess_1preprocess (__pyx_self=0x2aaac56d3b90, __pyx_args=0x2aaac55fc1e0, __pyx_kwds=0x2aaaaae61270 <_Py_NoneStruct>) at myprog/Preprocess.c:2700
#11 0x00002aaaaabab1e5 in call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffb908) at Python/ceval.c:4352
#12 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:2989
#13 0x00002aaaaabac345 in fast_function (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffba78, func=0x2aaac56ccc08) at Python/ceval.c:4437
#14 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffba78) at Python/ceval.c:4372
#15 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:2989
#16 0x00002aaaaabacc3e in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x2aaaab222a30, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=0, kws=0x0, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0)
at Python/ceval.c:3584
#17 0x00002aaaaabacd52 in PyEval_EvalCode (co=<optimized out>, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:669
#18 0x00002aaaaabcd450 in run_mod (arena=0x617e10, flags=0x7fffffffbd70, locals=0x2aaaaaf1b168, globals=0x2aaaaaf1b168, filename=<optimized out>, mod=0x6aaa70) at Python/pythonrun.c:1376
#19 PyRun_FileExFlags (fp=0x638fc0, filename=<optimized out>, start=<optimized out>, globals=0x2aaaaaf1b168, locals=0x2aaaaaf1b168, closeit=1, flags=0x7fffffffbd70) at Python/pythonrun.c:1362
#20 0x00002aaaaabcd62f in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags (fp=0x638fc0, filename=0x7fffffffc47f "/home/me/anaconda/bin/myprog", closeit=1, flags=0x7fffffffbd70) at Python/pythonrun.c:948
#21 0x00002aaaaabe2fd4 in Py_Main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at Modules/main.c:645
#22 0x00000033b881ed1d in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#23 0x0000000000400729 in _start ()

$ head -n 10678 /home/me/myprog_dist/versions/1.4.0/myprog-1.4.0/myprog/Snv.c | tail -n 1
PyThreadState *tstate = __Pyx_PyThreadState_Current;
```

I'm running python Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

I have no idea why this SegFault is happening. This package works on Arch Linux and MacOS. So why does it fail with CentOS?

Comment: "Chapeau!" to everyone who can tell you what your problem is without seeing the code...

Comment: The code is 1000s of lines long and works fine on other OSes. Could it be an issue with C libraries on CentOS?

Comment: Segmentation faults can happen unpredictably. The fact it works on some platforms really doesn't prove anything

Comment: I'd suggest turning `boundscheck` (and any other Cython optimizations) off - if you're lucky that might catch the bug

Comment: My final comment on this: I think "file not found" is because it's looking for that file to give you a better report on the segmentation fault and not finding it. I don't think the error is happening because the file isn't there.

Comment: You might at least get a bit more information if you run cython under faulthandler https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html